# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sksurv' in python

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, survival-analysis

I am trying to run survival analysis in python (pycharm) in linux, here is a part of the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sksurv.datasets import load_flchain
from sksurv.linear_model import CoxPHSurvivalAnalysis
```

I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sksurv'", I tried everything, but nothing works.

Comment: What is "everything"? Are you certain it's installed?

Comment: I installed Requirements

    Python 3.5 or later
    cvxpy
    cvxopt
    joblib
    numexpr
    numpy 1.12 or later
    osqp
    pandas 0.21 or later
    scikit-learn 0.22 or 0.23
    scipy 1.0 or later
    C/C++ compile

Comment: You shouldn't need to install the dependencies separately, when you install it, it'll automatically install required dependencies. It says [here](https://scikit-survival.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) that you need to install gcc also. Did you do that?

Comment: I installed gcc, do i need to install "pip install scikit-survival", I get the error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/myname/PycharmProjects/survival/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-usdsompl/osqp/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='..............

Comment: Try installing [CMake](https://cmake.org/download/) first, then rerun `pip install scikit-survival`. `osqp` requires CMake so that's probably what is causing the error.

Comment: It worked! I do not know to thank you. I am about to cry of happiness

Comment: Okay, I will post an answer so others who run into this problem can know it worked

Comment: It would be great. Thank you much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The required dependencies for `scikit-survival`,

- `cvxpy`
- `cvxopt`
- `joblib`
- `numexpr`
- `numpy` *1.12* or later
- `osqp`
- `pandas` *0.21* or later
- `scikit-learn` *0.22*
- `scipy` *1.0* or later

...will be automatically installed by `pip` when you run:

```
pip install scikit-survival
```

However, one module in particular, `osqp`, has [CMake](https://cmake.org) as one of its dependencies. If you don't have CMake installed, `pip install scikit-survival` will throw an error and the installation will fail.

You can download CMake for your OS at [cmake.org/download](https://cmake.org/download/)

After CMake has installed, you should be able to successfully run

```
pip install scikit-survival
```

Notes:

- [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) needs to be installed also
- `scikit-survival` works with Python 3.5 or higher
- More information is available in the [docs](https://scikit-survival.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)